# TimeSelector detecting only PM instead of Am

Tags: c#, time

I have a database table with two columns time1 and time2 respectively.Time1 contains `08:00 (08:00:00.000)` and time2 contains `17:30(17:30:00.000)`.Time1 and Time2 database field's datatype is `datetime` I have a code like

```
protected void txtdate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DateTime time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string time4 = time1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        str = "select TimeIn,TimeOut from MusterRoll where EmpCode='" + ddcode.SelectedItem.Text + "' and Date='"+time4+"'";
        dr = conn.query(str);
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            DateTime time = dr.GetDateTime(0);
            TimeSelector1.SetTime(time.Hour, time.Minute, TimeSelector1.AmPm);
            DateTime time2 = dr.GetDateTime(1);
            TimeSelector2.SetTime(time2.Hour, time2.Minute, TimeSelector2.AmPm);
        }

    }
```

code works properly but My TimeSelector1 shows 20:00 instead of 08:00  Time2 shows correct 17:30 time. how this code detects only PM? My timeSelector1  source ocde is

```
 <tr>
      <td align="left" class="style2">
      Punch I</td>
      <td align="left">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="input-prepend" title="Update Punch I" data-rel="tooltip">
     <cc1:timeselector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="False" 
      SelectedTimeFormat="TwentyFour">
     </cc1:timeselector>
     </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about your problem, unfortunately. But to me the string "17:30 PM(17:30:00.000)" looks wrong. Normally "PM" implies that you are specifying times in the am/pm system, so instead of "17:30 PM" I would expect "05:30 PM".

Comment: @RenniePet, it is in 24 hours format so 17:30

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But normally if you are using 24-hour times you do not include any "am" or "pm" indications. And if you include "am" and "pm" indications you do not specify times as 24-hour times. To me it looks strange that you have what looks like a confusing mixture.

Comment: OK, now you've edited your question to remove the "AM" and "PM" bits, so it looks like normal 24-hour formatting. Why does your first bit of programming contain "TimeSelector1.AmPm" and "TimeSelector2.AmPm"? (Although like I say, I know nothing about database programming and I know nothing about web-based forms, if that's what your second code sample is.)

Comment: @RenniePet, If I didnt add Timeselector1.AmPm it shows error like "No overload method "SetTime" takes two arguments". Thats why I added like this

Comment: @RenniePet, current time 10:00 Am also shows in 24 hour format ie as 22:00. why it shows like this??

Comment: Mr.Soner Gönül please help me to solve this issue